# заполнение EditText по курсору через баттон

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-button

интересует возможность заполнение EditText'а по расположению курсора через button.
То есть понятно что editText.append или .setText не подойдут. проще говоря надо что бы кастомные кнопки работали как обычная клавиатура андроидовская.

Comment: есть класс `KeyboardView` - делайте [какую хотите](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939816/7566397) себе клавиатуру

Comment: кастомная клавиатура не подойдёт. есть  кнопки в приложении, но они заполняют текст как клавиатура, то есть перенёскурсор в тексте и там начал писать, можно конечно сообразить что бы получал позицию курсора в EditText'e, и вставлял туда символ, а последующие символы автоматически заполнял, и будет эффект как от клавиатуры, но так кто либо делает?

Comment: здравствуйте не нашли случайно решения заполненияEdittext?

Comment: Здравствуй. сейчас напишу в ответах, тол как я с этим справился

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ......
public void someButton(View view){
        int position = editText.getSelectionStart();
        String tmpString = editText.getText().toString();
        editText.setText(tmpString.substring(0, position));
        editText.append((Button)view).getText().toString());
        editText.append(tmpString.substring(position, tmpString.length());
}
```